# <script> tag with style= attribute?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am reworking some old, hand-crafted HTML. Is the `style=` attribute doing anything here?

```
<script type="text/javascript" style="behavior:url(#default#clientcaps)" id="..." src="..."></script>
```

I find a lot of hits searching for `style=behavior:url(#default#clientcaps)}`, but will this have any effect on a `<script>` tag?

Answer (score 2):

`style` is not a valid attribute on a `<script>` element ([W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html)), so it's not doing anything. Even Internet Explorer, which is the only browser that supports CSS behaviors, is ignoring it.

Answer (score 1):

It is some ugly [MS stuff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531416%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

> Provides information about features supported by Windows Internet Explorer, as well as a way for installing browser components on demand.

Try get get to the person who added it and tell him he's a bad guy! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case the style attribute is used just for a short hand for creating a style tag.

short for:

```
<STYLE>
@media all {
   IE\:clientCaps {behavior:url(#default#clientCaps)}
}   
</STYLE>
```

Its specific to Internet Explorer. For what it does exactly you can read more here:
[clientCaps Behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531416%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)